# Do something when nested/transcluded directives have been compiled and linked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-transclude

Think about something like the following directive markup:

```
<!-- Directive A -->
<directive-a>
</directive-a>

<-- Directive B -->
<directive-b>
   <directive-a>
        <transclusion1></transclusion1>
   </directive-a>
</directive-b>
```

I need to perform some DOM manipulation once the `<directive-a>` has been already compiled+linked from `<directive-b>`.

When I provide a `link` function on `<directive-b>` (or `compile` function), `<directive-a>` is still without its transcluded content.

I can't figure out how to perform that DOM manipulation once the `<directive-a>` has been already compiled+linked.

Comment: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful.

Comment: @estus Not on this case... I'm about to find the solution since Angular 1.5.3+ has hooks. I doubt that a MCVE would help here, because my problem isn't a bug, error or whatever: it's a concept and I need to know how to implement it in Angular.

Comment: Transcluded elements are already available in `link` function and `$postLink` hook. As you wish.

Comment: @estus if this were true... I wouldn't be here to ask a question :D

Comment: You will hardly get another answer without investing some time in posting your own directives.

Comment: @estus You can check it, I've already answered myself ;D

Comment: `post-link` callback looks like a hack, good for you if this works. It looks like nested directives have templateUrl in your case. The good pattern here is to communicate from children to parent with `require`d controller or scope event, not in the opposite direction.

Comment: @estus The issue in my case is that the equivalent directive to directiveA is unrelated to directB. Because directiveA is a component to harmonize all other ui components to generalize UX with some common behaviors and look&feel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the solution is easier than I thought when I started to implement the solution.

Let's say there's the `<directive-a>` with the following options:

```
{
    scope: {
        "postLink": "&"
    }
}
```

...and, as part of `controller()` function I do:

```
{
    controller: () => {
        // Angular 1.5.3+
        this.$postLink = $scope.postLink;
    },
    scope: {
        "postLink": "&"
    }
}
```

Now I can hook to `<directive-a>` `$postLink` hook:

```
<-- Directive B -->
<directive-b>
   <directive-a post-link="model.directiveAPostLink()">
        <transclusion1></transclusion1>
   </directive-a>
</directive-b>
```

When the whole `model.directiveAPostLink()` function is called, `<directive-a>` is already compiled and linked!

### Further details

Checking Angular GitHub's repository commit history, [I've found the following description:](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/9cd9956dcbc8382e8e8757a805398bd251bbc67e)

> `$postLink` - Called after this controller's element and its children
>   been linked. Similar to the post-link    function this hook can be
>   used to set up DOM event handlers and do direct DOM manipulation.
>
> Note that child elements that contain `templateUrl` directives will
>   not have been compiled and linked since    they are waiting for their
>   template to load asynchronously and their own compilation and linking
>   has been    suspended until that occurs.

It's exactly my case: I'm loading templates from an URL.